# How to stop a simple javascript conflict between pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have 2 pages top.php and my Currentpage.php.  The top page has the newest version of Jquery and Bootstrap.  The current page has code that I can't upgrade just yet.  Is there a way to stop the top.php Javascript code after it loads then have the currentpage.php Javascript load?

top.php has:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="../bootstrap/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body> 
<!-- some code here for top navigation -->
```

Currentpage.php has this:

```
<head>
<script type="style/js/jquery.form-2.47.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="style/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.dialog.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
include "../includes/top.php";
?>
<!-- stop the top.php code here then load the current page Javascript code -->
</body>
```

Comment: so you want to load two versions of jquery and bootstrap?

Comment: Yes.  I have 2 versions of jquery, and bootstrap the Javascript conflicts with the other javascript on the page

Comment: Where is `Currentpage.php` loading jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach may be to read in the text file (as opposed to using an include) and remove the Javascript line then write out the contents. Something like this:

```
$str=file_get_contents('top.php');
$str=str_replace("<script src=\"../bootstrap/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>", "",$str);
$str=str_replace("<script src=\"../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>", "",$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just turns everything to text.  Was the replace for the other version (from newer to older)>

Comment: I was just thinking maybe there is a way to frame the php window somehow?

Comment: SDJ. I just tried the code I gave you in a test file and it worked. Its output was:

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    
    
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
     
    </head>
    <body>

Comment: You are right.  I must have something else in my code getting in the way (that I didn't put in here from pages of code)

Answer (score 2):

I use a variable to tell `top.php` not to load jQuery.

top.php:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php if (!isset($jquery_loaded)) { ?>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../bootstrap/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body> 
<!-- some code here for top navigation -->
```

Currentpage.php:

```
<head>
    <script type="style/js/jquery.form-2.47.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="style/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.dialog.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$jquery_loaded = true;
include "../includes/top.php";
?>
<!-- stop the top.php code here then load the current page Javascript code -->
</body>
```

Comment: I really liked this approach too!